# Scala Akka Quickstart: Java Version Mismatch and Compilation Error

Tags: java, scala, java-8, concurrency, akka

I am relatively new to Scala and Akka, transitioning from a Java, Spring, and REST API background. Currently, I am working through the Akka Actors Quickstart with Scala tutorial.

Upon attempting to run the Hello World example for Scala, following the provided steps, I encountered an issue when executing `sbt reStart`. The error message is as follows:

```
akka-quickstart-scala[ERROR] Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
akka-quickstart-scala[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: akka/actor/typed/ActorSystem has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

After researching, I found suggestions to upgrade the JRE to version 11, but due to constraints, I cannot do so at the moment. Attempting to compile the code in Java 8 using `scalac AkkaQuickstart.scala` resulted in the following error:

```
AkkaQuickstart.scala:5: error: not found: object akka
import http://akka.actor.typed.ActorRef
```

Given that I'm a novice in Akka and Scala, and unable to upgrade the Java version, I am seeking guidance on resolving this version mismatch and compilation error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first error says that the class is compiled for Java 11. The second one probably is because you only use scalac without adding anything to the classpath. If this is a new project, why you can't use Java 11?

Comment: @GastónSchabas :  Thank you for your comment. I appreciate your suggestion. Regarding the scalac, I already tried changing the directory and to the class itself. As for Java 11, unfortunately, I am not able to download JDK on my own and have to rely on the version available in the company's App Store. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If you generated the project using `sbt new akka/akka-quickstart-scala.g8` or downloaded the zip from [Akka Actors Quickstart with Scala](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/), the project comes from [akka-quickstart-scala.g8](https://github.com/akka/akka-quickstart-scala.g8). The [build.sbt](https://github.com/akka/akka-quickstart-scala.g8/blob/d59095f7e0c9d1a921ab6fef36cdf71b1d645e02/src/main/g8/build.sbt) has [default akka version 2.9](https://github.com/akka/akka-quickstart-scala.g8/blob/d59095f7e0c9d1a921ab6fef36cdf71b1d645e02/src/main/g8/default.properties#L3)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Gastón @gastón-schabas. I have checked the project's build.sbt file and found the specified Akka version is indeed 2.9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Akka 2.9 - Support for Java 8 removed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.9/project/migration-guide-2.8.x-2.9.x.html#support-for-java-8-removed)

> #### Support for Java 8 removed
>
> The published artifacts are targeting Java 11, and later. Supported Java versions are 11 and 17.

The [PR to drop jdk 8 support](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/32127) was merged

[Akka 2.9 - Support for Scala 2.12 removed](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.9/project/migration-guide-2.8.x-2.9.x.html#support-for-scala-2-12-removed)

> #### Support for Scala 2.12 removed
>
> The published artifacts are targeting Scala 2.13 and Scala 3.3.

Which means, if you only are able to run your projects using jdk 8, the latest version of akka you can use is 2.8.x.

I was able to run locally the following dummy akka hello world

- `build.sbt`

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.12"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "akka-dummy-hello-world",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.8.5"
    )
  )
```

- `Main.scala`

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val empty = Behaviors.setup[Any] { _ =>
      println("hello akka dummy")
      Behaviors.empty
    }
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem(empty, "akka-dummy-hello-world")
    actorSystem.terminate()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gastón, for your response and for doing some local testing for the dummy akka hello world project. I appreciate your effort and for letting me know about the removed support for Java 8 in the latest version of akka.
Your suggestion to use akka-actor-typed version 2.8.5 with Scala version 2.13.12 worked perfectly for me, and I was able to run the dummy hello world example.
Again, thank you for your guidance and support. I'm grateful for your help and have accepted your answer.